# using real instead of really

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I sometimes hear YouTubers say "something is real good" is it okay to use real instead of really?
can I say "I am real proud of you?"

Answer (score 2):

It's a very informal usage.  Technically, **really** is an adverb and **real** is an adjective, but people do use *real* as an adverb sometimes.  You should only use it in very informal contexts, like speaking with your friends.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/real:

> **Definition of *real* (Entry 2 of 5)**
> *chiefly US, informal*
> : VERY, REALLY —used as an intensifier
> // It was a good furnace all last winter, they didn't have a single problem with it: it ran *real* quiet …
> — Garrison Keillor 
> // … the magazine isn't *real* sure who its readers are …
> — Tom Carson

Comment: Mainly a US usage, although you do hear it elsewhere.